# Computing the gradient in a discrete $\mathbb{R}^3$ without a function : is this correct?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, 3d

> Given a $3$D mesh, which is nothing more than a set of points with coordinates on the $3$axis, I follow the intuitive definition of *gradient*, which means I'm trying to get the "slope".

Following the instructions in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669288/trying-to-calculate-the-slope-of-a-plane-from-a-normal), it's possible to define the result of the final `arccos` as a gradient ?

Starting from a set of points and normals, it's possible to compute the slope in another way?

Comment: I assume that discrete geometry is not that popular around here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a surface with equation $z=f(x,y)$, the magnitude of the gradient $|\nabla f|$ could indeed be called the slope of the surface. (This matches the terminology  for $y=f(x)$, except here we don't talk about negative slope.) Understood in this way, the slope is the *tangent* of  the angle $\theta$ between the normal vector and the vertical direction. So, if this is the quantity that you want, and your normal vector is $(u,v,w)$, then the formula you got at SO
$$\cos\theta = \frac{w}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2}}$$
leads to the slope being
$$\tan\theta =  \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}-1 = \frac{u^2+v^2}{ w^2 }$$
Whether $\theta$ or $\tan\theta$ is more useful for your purpose, I can't tell.

You may also want to look at the algorithm that Matlab uses for the [numerical gradient](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html).

Comment: it's possible to get a vector instead of a simple scalar ?

Comment: @user2485710 That's what the Matlab algorithm does. It works with values of function itself (as in your post here), not with normal vectors (as in your post on SO).

Comment: I don't have a function, I simply have a set of points in R^3

Comment: @user2485710 The Z-coordinates of your points is what I called the values of the function. You have those.

Comment: yes, I get your post, I mean I can't apply the algorithm from Matlab if it requires a function ...

Comment: f(x,y) = my z ... I'm dumb :|

Comment: ok, I would like to know if I'm right, basically that algorithm says that my `z` is equivalent to the sum of the derivative of x and the derivative of y ? And so the coordinates of the vector that I want are [ d_x, d_y, z ] ?

Comment: @user2485710  The gradient of a function $z=f(x,y)$ is a 2D vector $[d_x,d_y]$. One can numerically calculate $d_x$ and $ d_y$ if  the values of $f$ are known on a rectangular grid in $xy$-plane. If the $xy$ values you have are not from a 2D grid, then a more sophisticated approach is required. It will probably involve some interpolation method, with gradient obtained from the interpolating function.